# Trouble with my ajax post script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok so my ajax goes as follows - when someone clicks this link:

```
$echo " | <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\"  id=".$larray['idnum']." class=\"deleterow\">Delete Friend</a>";
```

I use an ajax/jquery to send the data to delete_ajax.php

```
$(".deleterow").click( function() {
    $('.deleterow').attr('id');
    var dr= $(this).attr('id');
    $.post("delete_ajax.php", { id: dr } );
} );
```

Can someone just double check that this is all correct?

Comment: What's the point of this line? `$('.deleterow').attr('id');`

Comment: Why not test it and see if your php script gets anything? We're not proofreaders here...

Comment: I did and the link ends up doing nothing

Comment: Do you think that something gets done by giving it the right filename?

Comment: guys, this is a legit question. the only thing he did was instead of saying "this don't work, what am i doing wrong", he said "double check my code"

Answer (score 3):

First, check if your code is being executed in the document load event. For that, enclose all jquery code inside a `$(function(){ ... })`

Then, instead of `id=".$larray['idnum']."`, use `data-id=".$larray['idnum']."` and:

```
$(".deleterow").click( function() {
    $.post("delete_ajax.php", { id: $(this).data('id'); } );
} );
```

Finally, instead of `<a>` you can do this using a `<div>`, just add `cursor:pointer` to it's class or style so the cursor is shaped like a hand.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED FLAWLESSLY! I've tried to figure this out for almost 8hrs =D!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why I'm responding to this but w/e

You should be communicating with your server with handshake-like requests. A request should be acknowledged on both sides to understand if the event was successful or not.

in delete_ajax.php ....

```
if ($this->db->delete('table', 'where ..')){
   echo json_encode(array('result'=>1, 'message'=>'delete successful'));
} else {
   echo json_encode(array('result'=>0, 'message'=>'delete unusuccessful'));
}
```

Have your ajax acknowledge the response.

```
$(".deleterow").click( function() {
    // $('.deleterow').attr('id'); // pointless..
    var dr= $(this).attr('id');
    $.post( "delete_ajax.php", 
       { id: dr },
       function (reponse){
           alert(response['message']);
       }, 'json'
    );
} );
```